# ¿Cómo usar el método populate con findById en Mongoose cuando falla la query?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy creando una ruta en Express con Mongoose. No estoy entendiendo como tratar el caso en que la query no encuentra el ID que llega como parámetro por medio de la requisición. En mi cabeza sería algo así:

```
router.get('/:userId', (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.userId;

  User.findById(userId)
  .populate('photos')
  .exec((err, userFound) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      if (!userFound) {
        res.send('Not found!);
      } else {
        res.json(userFound);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Pero, si envío una requisición con un ID que no existe, recibo el siguiente error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "59a6106150367d57b301312" at path "_id" for model "User"
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

`User.findById(userId)` tienes que ser así => `User.findById({"_id": userId})`. Ese es el error que te muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Sí, usa el método status y send del objeto res (response). Status para enviar el [status](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP) de la petición y send para enviar el cuerpo, en este caso un objeto con atributo llamado "error" con valor de una cadena. Aquí puedes colocar otro valor, como el "err" que retorna el callback de la búsqueda.

```
router.get('/:userId', (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.userId;

  User.findById(userId)
  .populate('photos')
  .exec((err, userFound) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send({ error: 'No se encontró el usuario'})
      // O usar: return res.status(500).send({ error: 'No se encontró el usuario con valor' + userId}) o envía el objeto err
    } else {
      if (!userFound) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Hubo un error al buscar al usuario'})
      } else {
        return res.status(200).send(userFound)
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Nota que coloqué return en los errores para que se termine la ejecución. Es mejor práctica enviar las respuestas tanto de error como de success por la cuestión de las cabeceras.

Comment: J.Correa, cuando implemento la solución que propones, recibo siempre una respuesta 400, o sea que el else no llega a ser evaluado. Por el momento, moví el condicional que evalúa si el usuario fue encontrado antes del return status 400. Pero bueno, no sé si es lo correcto.

Comment: Eso pasa porque está dando un error. 

Cambia ese renglón y pon...    return res.status(400).send(err) ... o has un console.log(err) para que veas el error que te marca.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, aparentemente el problema está en que Mongoose no reconoce el ID que estoy colocando en la URL de la requisición como un ID válido. Usé el ID de un usuario que existe y le quité el último número, y por lo visto el ID tiene que tener una determinada cantidad de dígitos. Por eso es que nunca llega a evaluar si el usuario existe o no y el mensaje de error que presenta es el correcto.

Comment: En ese caso mi respuesta es correcta porque enviar un ID inválido hace que tu consulta retorne un error, en este caso entra al if (err) ... de igual manera, debes tener en cuenta que otros errores son posibles como un ID que sí es válido pero que NO exista en la colección. Mi respuesta contempla ambos casos

Comment: J.Correa, tu respuesta reproduce exactamente la misma lógica que posté en el original, con la diferencia de que tú estás usando código de respuesta y returns. Pero eso no modifica nada, porque el problema no estaba en la lógica sino en que no estaba entendiendo que el error se producía antes y qué significaba. Es lo que te estaba explicando cuando dije que implementando tu solución (returns y códigos de respuesta) no sucedía nada diferente. El error fue informado en el post original.

Comment: Dijiste que "No estoy entendiendo como tratar el caso en que la query no encuentra el ID que llega como parámetro por medio de la requisición.", y bueno, la manera de tratar el caso en que la query no encuentra el ID es como lo puse en mi respuesta. Al final dices que te sale un error cuando envías un ID inexistente, con lo que yo respondí te retorna un mensaje personalizado y evita que aparezca un Cast Error. Lo que dices ahoraya es algo diferente a tu post original, más bien querías **entender por qué te daba error**, algo **muy distinto a cómo tratar ese error**

Comment: Evidentemente, no nos estamos entendiendo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, incluso el título de tu pregunta es: "¿Cómo usar el método populate con findById en Mongoose cuando falla la query?", eso es diferente a "¿Cuál es la causa del error al hacer findById enviando x ID?". Te sugiero repasar la sección de ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask